# Jquery Array - how to condense multiple index initialisations to a single line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can the following 5 lines be condensed into a single line array?

```
var exmplArray = [];
exmplArray['hours'] = 0;
exmplArray['overtime'] = 0;
exmplArray['income'] = 0;
exmplArray['expenditure'] = 0;
```

I have tried the following but an error kicks in: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'

```
var exmplArray = ['hours' = 0, 'overtime' = 0, 'income' = 0, 'expenditure' = 0];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use object `{}` instead when you need a "hash" in javascript:

```
var example = {};
example['hours'] = 0;
example['overtime'] = 0;
example['income'] = 0;
example['expenditure'] = 0;
```

or

```
// the quote could be ommitted.
var example = { 'hours': 0, 'overtime': 0, 'income': 0, 'expenditure': 0 };
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var exmplArray = {'hours' :0, 'overtime' :0, 'income' :0, 'expenditure' :0};
```